# JSONP parse error with jquery ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have the following jquery ajax request:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: serverAddress+'php/product.php',
    type: 'GET',
        jsonpCallback: "callback7",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: sendInfo,
    success: function(result)
            {
                alert(result);
                //do something
            },
    error:function(jqXHR,msg,errorThrown){ alert(msg+" : "+errorThrown);}
  });
```

on the server side the script is:

```
$callback = $_GET['callback'];
//do something
$result = //something
echo $callback.'('.json_encode($result).')';
```

I get the following error from the ajax call:

parseerror : callback7 was not called

I looked up this error but couldn't find anything relevant, either in SO or in google...
Hope you can help me.
Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I eventually solved the problem by transforming it into a regular json request.
I'll be happy to know what could be the problem ans solution nevertheless.

Comment: is there  a method named `callback7` in your javascript.. if no remove the `jsonpCallback` property and change the url to `serverAddress+'php/product.php?callback=?'` then

Comment: So I tried changing the parameters like you said but it just gave me the same error a bit different: "parsererror : jQuery<some long number with hyphens in the middle> was not called". Is there more after the "then"?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these name value pair as **jsonp:false & crossDomain:true** in your js file.         And in your server side remove the line $_Get['callback'] and add echo **$callback.'('.json_encode($result).')'** and alse set **$callback='callback7'**

Comment: So if that doesn't work instead of using ajax call use this....                                            $.getJson(url+"?callback=?",callback7);